# Dojo moveable for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am creating dynamic html element using dojo domConstruct as below,

```
//ID, all style parameters are available in function 
var vertex = domConstruct.create("div", {
  id: node.ID,
  "class": type,
  style: {
    left: node.position.x +'px',
    top: node.position.y +'px',
    border: colorBorder.border,
    'box-shadow': colorBorder.boxShadow,
    backgroundColor: colorBorder.backgroundColor,
    position:'absolute'
  },
  innerHTML: nodeName
}, "statemachine-demo");
```

I have to make this element moveable ,  Therefore I am using dojo Moveable as below,

```
//using dojo Moveable    
var moveableHandle = new Moveable(vertex);
console.log("priting moveable object before passing to adapter",moveableObject);
```

When I run it  log shows following lines,

```
priting moveable object before passing to adapter 
Object
  delay: 0
  events: null
  handle: null
  mover: function (){
  node: null
  onMove: function (){
  onMoveStart: function (){
  onMoveStop: function (){
  skip: undefined
  __proto__: Object
```

I don't understand, why handle and node remains null ? Ideally there should be reference to moveable element.

Is it because, element is not present in Dom when Moveable is being applied ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using setTimeout which delays creation on Moveable object,

```
//using lang.hitch for passing the context
setTimeout(lang.hitch(this,new function(){

 //vertex from the context 
 var moveableHandle = new Moveable(vertex);
 console.log("priting moveable object before passing to adapter",moveableObject);

 //do stuff with moveable .....

}),1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in the variables you have used. I used absolute values instead of the variables like node, type, colorborder you have used in your program and it worked just fine for me. Please check these values.

Also make sure that "statemachine-demo" is a proper id name, or use domConstruct.place method.

You can check the working version of the sample - [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ5Rt/3/).

```
   require(["dojo/dnd/Moveable", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"],

    function(Moveable, dom, on, domConstruct) {
        on(dom.byId("doIt"), "click", function() {
            var vertex = domConstruct.create("div", {
                id: 'id1',
                class: "class1",
                style: {
                    left: 200 + 'px',
                    top: 200 + 'px',
                    border: '1px',
                    'box-shadow': '10px 10px 5px #888888',
                    backgroundColor: 'green',
                    position: 'absolute'
                },
                innerHTML: 'aaaaaaaaaaa'
            }, "dndArea");
            var dnd1 = new Moveable(vertex);
            console.log(dnd1);
        });
    });
```